# How to calculate correlations(COT report) in R ?

Tags: correlation

First thing i want to do is load data(.csv) into R. The data i am concentrating are the COT reports. Want to load a single column into R and calculate the correlation with the proper instrument.

Comment: This question is more suited for the `r` tag on StackOverflow.

Comment: Just to add, if your question had more relevance to the *COT*, then this would be on-topic.  As it stands, it seems like it's mostly just a pure programming question.  Feel free to revise it if you think that you can make it more relevant.